# Minimum turn required to modify given array to make it increasing

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

You are given an array of n integers. You want to modify the array so that it is increasing, i.e., every element is at least as large as the previous element.

On each turn, you may increase the value of any element by one. What is the minimum number of turns required?

Example:

```
Input = 3 2 5 1 7
Output = 5

steps: 

1 => 3 2+1 5 1 7
2 => 3 3 5 1+1 7
3 => 3 3 5 2+1 7
4 => 3 3 5 3+1 7
5 => 3 3 5 4+1 7
```

So it will take 5 turns to make this array increasing.

My approch in Python:

```
def makeIncreasingArray(arr, count=1):
    temp = []
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] >= arr[i - 1]:
            temp.append(True)
        else:
            arr[i] += 1
            temp.append(False)
            
    if sum(temp) == len(arr) - 1:
        return count
    else:
        count += 1
        return makeIncreasingArray(arr, count)
```

It's working but I think this one is more like bruteforce solution.
How can I make this code better?

Comment: If your code works and you want to improve it, please post your question to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using NumPy, you can implement this as `(np.maximum.accumulate(arr) - arr).sum()`.

E.g.

```
import numpy as np

def count_turns(x):
    return (np.maximum.accumulate(x) - x).sum()
```

In action,

```
In [18]: x = [3, 2, 5, 1, 7]

In [19]: count_turns(x)
Out[19]: 5
```

If you want to stick with "pure" Python, you can do the same thing, with a little help from `itertools.accumulate` to replace `np.maximum.accumulate`.  For example,

```
In [22]: from itertools import accumulate

In [23]: x = [3, 2, 5, 1, 7]

In [24]: list(accumulate(x, max))
Out[24]: [3, 3, 5, 5, 7]
```

Then the element-wise subtraction can be implemented using zip and a list comprehension:

```
In [25]: [cmax - t for cmax, t in zip(accumulate(x, max), x)]                                                                                            
Out[25]: [0, 1, 0, 4, 0]
```

Finally, the number of turns is the sum of those differences:

```
In [26]: sum(cmax - t for cmax, t in zip(accumulate(x, max), x))                                                                                         
Out[26]: 5
```

Putting that into a function gives

```
from itertools import accumulate

def count_turns(x):
    return sum(cmax - t for cmax, t in zip(accumulate(x, max), x))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right. Shouldn't the output of `[100] + [0] * 20` be more around 100 rather than 2000? (Double check step 1)

Comment: @Peilonrayz, to transform [100] + [0]*20 to a nondecreasing sequence using "turns" as defined in the question ("on each turn, you may increase the value of any element by one"), all 20 of the zeros must be increased to 100.  20*100 is 2000.

Comment: "1 => 3 2+1 5 1+1 7" Notice the two +1s in one turn

Comment: But then the result for [3, 2, 5, 1, 7] should be 4, not 5.  I'd ask for clarification in the question, but the question is closed, so on to other things...

Comment: Sorry my bad, @WarrenWeckesser you should only increment one element per turn

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is to keep adding 1 to each element that’s smaller than the one preceding it until the array is increasing.

Think about the *first* element that’s too small. You’ll keep adding 1 to it until it’s equal to the number before it. Because nothing is changing before this element (it’s the first element that’s wrong), once it’s equal to the number before it, it’ll never need to change again. So you can do all the steps at once (let’s say that `i` is the index of this first wrong element):

```
while arr[i] < arr[i - 1]:
    arr[i] += 1
    count += 1
```

Maybe with this smaller example, it’ll be clearer that this can be done without a loop (i.e. much faster):

```
if arr[i] < arr[i - 1]:
    count += arr[i - 1] - arr[i]
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1]
```

And since this does nothing on elements that are *not* wrong, all you need to do now is apply it to every element in order:

```
def make_increasing_array(arr):
    count = 0

    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] < arr[i - 1]:
            count += arr[i - 1] - arr[i]
            arr[i] = arr[i - 1]

    return count
```

Finally, there’s no need to alter the input if you keep track of `arr[i - 1]` separately:

```
def make_increasing_array(arr):
    if not arr:
        return 0

    count = 0
    last = arr[0]

    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] < last:
            count += last - arr[i]
        else:
            last = arr[i]

    return count
```